# Does a.run same as a?.run in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

If a variable is nullable in Kotlin, we need to either do a safety call ?., or !!. for explicitly call.

When I was trying to use some extensions(such as run or let) from nullable variable , I noticed that .run is fine and IDE did not complain it, usually I will receive a warning to remind me it is not a safety call.

Does it make any difference for ?.run{} and .run{} in kotlin? Is it considered as null safety if I use .run{} ?

```
var a? = "..."

a?.run{}

a.run{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to safely handle the null somewhere.

Either when accessing `a`:

```
a?.run { }
```

Or when accessing `this` inside `run` on `a`:

```
a.run { this?.toSomething() }
```

Using a `String?` as an example, these both print `null` and the compiler is ok with both:

```
val x: String? = null
println(x.run { this?.toUpperCase() }) // prints null, type is String?
println(x?.run { this.toUpperCase() }) // prints null, type is String?
```